# No Instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is availablefor scala.collection.immutable.List[Item]

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

Note: I'm very new to PlayFramework.

I'm trying to serialise an item object into a JSON String. I receive the following error:

```
 No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for 
 scala.collection.immutable.List[Item] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared
 in the same file, make sure it's declared before)

 [error]   implicit val itemRESTFormat: Format[ItemREST] = 
 Json.format[ItemREST]
```

I really don't understand what the error means at all, or have any idea what is going wrong. If someone could explain to me what the error means, and what the potential issue could be, that would be great. Thanks!

```
import...

case class ItemREST(items: List[Item]) {
    def toJson: String = Json.toJson(this).as[JsObject].toString()
}

object ItemREST {
    implicit val itemRESTFormat: Format[ItemREST] = Json.format[ItemREST]

    def fromItem(items: List[Item]): ItemREST = {
        ItemREST(items)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the `ItemREST` has list of elements of type `Item`. Hence for serializing `ItemREST`, serializer for `Item` is required.

```
object Item {
  implicit val itemFormat = Json.format[Item]
}

object ItemREST {
  implicit val itemRESTFormat: Format[ItemREST] = Json.format[ItemREST]
}
```

You just need to declare the serializer of Item before ItemREST and that will solve your problem.

Also, one thing that you could try out is to add the

```
implicit val itemFormat = Json.format[Item]
```

just before the

```
  implicit val itemRESTFormat: Format[ItemREST] = Json.format[ItemREST]
```

The complete code would look like this

```
case class Item(i : Int)
case class ItemList(list : List[Item])

object ItemList{
  implicit  val itemFormat = Json.format[Item]
  implicit  val itemListFormat = Json.format[ItemList]
}


object SOQ extends App {

  println(Json.toJson(ItemList(List(Item(1),Item(2)))))

}
```

giving you n output as

```
{"list":[{"i":1},{"i":2}]}
```

Comment: I tried this out but I receive the exact same error

Comment: @Chris did you please all of them in the same file ?

Comment: Walkar Yes I put the `object Item {...} ` before everything except for the imports

Comment: It worked when I put the implicit val statement inside the ItemREST object, not the Item object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That what I was going to suggest now. I just tried that code in my IDE and was going to paste it here. Anyways good that it worked out for you. I am editing my answer, please accept it